# URL amigável ASP Clássico com Isapi Rewrite

Tags: asp, iis, web.config, url-rewrite, plesk

Bom dia, pessoal.

A questão é que eu consigo acessar um endereço `dominio.com/modulo/id/titulo` e ele reescrever para `dominio.com/default.asp?link=artigo&id=123&titulo=teste`, mas minha dúvida é se consigo fazer o processo reverso, ou seja, acessar `dominio.com/default.asp?link=artigo&id=123&titulo=teste` e ele alterar para `dominio.com/modulo/id/titulo`.

Códigos:

**ASP**

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="pt-br"><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><title>Teste Isapi Rewrite</title></head><body><p>Teste!<br>link: <%=request("link")%><br>id: <%=request("id")%><br>teste: <%=request("teste")%><br></p></body></html>
```

**WEB.CONFIG**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="artigo" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^artigo/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?$" />
                <conditions> 
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" /> 
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" /> 
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="default.asp?link={R:0}&amp;id={R:1}&amp;teste={R:2}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido com as seguinte regras:

```
<rule name="reverse" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="default.asp" />
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="link=(.*)\&amp;id=(.*)\&amp;titulo=(.*)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/{C:1}/{C:2}/{C:3}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
<rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="default.asp?link={R:1}&amp;id={R:2}&amp;titulo={R:3}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57760191/url-friendly-asp-classic-and-isapi-rewrite